# ASP.NET Core 6.0: Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.IMapper'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4v7h.png)
I have installed both **AutoMapper** and **AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection**

But still I am getting the same error

Comment: Please provide the exception message and trace as text in your questions. Also the exception is clear. Installing the package is not enough. Read up on the documentation of Automapper how to set up dependency injection in your application startup.

Comment: this is resolved

Answer (score 0):

I didn't add the builder.services line in program.cs file that is

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score -1):

Have you added it in Program.cs like

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(config =>
{
    config.AddProfile(typeof(YourMappingProfile));
});
```